# filter array in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

i have this array:

```
[
  {
    "title": "fruit",
    "categories": [
      "apple",
      "banana"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "city",
    "categories": [
      "Brazil",
      "EUA",
      "China"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "name",
    "categories": [
      "Ana"
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to filter this by any terms that the users type

i already got this, works only for title, but i want to search by title and category:

```js
array.filter(f => f.title.includes(myString))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate with `||` with a `.some` check on `f.categories`:

```
array.filter(f =>
  f.title.includes(myString) ||
  f.categories.some(
    category => category.includes(myString)
  )
);
```

Live demo:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "title": "fruit",
    "categories": [
      "apple",
      "banana"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "city",
    "categories": [
      "Brazil",
      "EUA",
      "China"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "name",
    "categories": [
      "Ana"
    ]
  }
];

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = JSON.stringify(
    array.filter(f =>
      f.title.includes(input.value) ||
      f.categories.some(
        category => category.includes(input.value)
      )
    )
  );
});
```

```html
<input>
<div></div>
```

This isn't the logic your original code is implementing, but if you also need to check for different case matches:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "title": "fruit",
    "categories": [
      "apple",
      "banana"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "city",
    "categories": [
      "Brazil",
      "EUA",
      "China"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "name",
    "categories": [
      "Ana"
    ]
  }
];

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const value = input.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelector('div').textContent = JSON.stringify(
    array.filter(f =>
      f.title.toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      f.categories.some(
        category => category.toLowerCase().includes(value)
      )
    )
  );
});
```

```html
<input>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Can you please add as to what `.some` does? I like this answer but I want to understand better. Also, for title, can we do `f.title === myString` correct? Because title is not an array.

Comment: `.some` will return `true` if any of the items of the array being iterated over pass the test. So, here, it will return `true` if any items in `f.categories` contain `myString`. You *can* do `f.title === myString`, but that will only result in items being included if they're an *exact match* - OP seems to want a match when *any character* is included.

Comment: When we pass `ana` as `myString` it returns just the fruit part. Maybe we need to return name as well. Can we do this : `category => category.toLowerCase().includes('ana')` to cover that? Also, probably do `myString = myString.toLowerCase()`. Just a suggestion!

Comment: Same for the title as well!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want items that match your title and category, you can do this to get an array of matches.

```
array.filter(f => f.title === 'myTitle' && f.categories.includes('myCategory'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough if you just want to filter by title or category

```js
const array = [
  {
    "title": "fruit",
    "categories": [
      "apple",
      "banana"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "city",
    "categories": [
      "Brazil",
      "EUA",
      "China"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "name",
    "categories": [
      "Ana"
    ]
  }
]

const string = 'Brazil'// whatever the user types

const result = array.filter(f => f.title === string || f.categories.includes(string))
console.log(result);
```